# A word for a person who never overpays

Tags: single-word-requests

What do I call a person who always seeks for the best price on particular item/product/service ?

Person who spends hours digging internet to find deals/discount codes/coupons in order to pay a minimum price ?

Same person may also bargain for hours with any service provider, like a car dealer, barber or street hot-dog seller, etc.

It can be in a form of addiction but also can be considered as good quality of person (he is smart enough never to overpay)

Comment: Related: [What's a word that means a person tries to find an easier, cheaper way?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273195), [Is there a word/idiom for someone who thinks long and hard before spending money?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/307706)

Comment: Are you looking for a noun or an adjective to describe this person? If you are looking for a single word, as it seems, could you please tag your post "single-word-request"? Thanks!

Comment: "Frugal" is the first term that comes to mind.

Comment: @sumelic Those refer to adjectives like stingy, thrifty, etc. I took it to mean a noun.

Comment: I waited before casting my vote to close this question. The OP should now explain why the older question does not answer this one, and specifically say if they are looking for a noun or an adjective.

Answer (score 4):

First off, I'm going to assume that you don't want a word such as thrifty, because you want a greater emphasis on the condition, and that you don't want a word with a negative connotation such as stingy or tightfisted.

The first phrase that comes to mind is [bargain-hunter](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bargain%20hunter), which I have heard many times personally, and implies an intensity of desire to seek out lower prices without the negative overtones usually associated with being cheap.